# TFS Merge:Invalid change-sets as merge candidates

Tags: tfs

In a TFS repository I have a Main branch and a child Dev branch. I have recently created a child branch from my Dev branch: DevChild.

I need to merge changes made in Dev up to DevChild but the changeset creating the Dev branch is incorrectly appearing as a merge candidate.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You have Dev which has changes. You have a child branch of dev without. You merge from Dev to DevChild. You will get changes in DevChild you need to checkin. What is the issue?

Comment: The actual branching changeset appears as a merge candidate.

Comment: You mean that you are merging from DevChild to Dev?